# creating an Async task inside a service

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

I am trying to implement an Async task that gets a string from a url inside a service.
I am using a startedService which calls the Async task get the correct string, update a public DB class content and return to the main activity, the problem is that the list adapter which i need to notify of the change in the DB is at the main activity and i don't have access to it from the Service , I am a a noobie so I am not familiar with what better to use , started or bind service for that job, any sugestions ?

thank you

Comment: You can use `BroadcastReceiver` for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BroadcastReceiver :
In your Activity:

```
    @Override
public void onResume() {
  super.onResume();

  // Register mMessageReceiver to receive messages.
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
      new IntentFilter("mybroadcast"));
}

// handler for received Intents for the "my-event" event 
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Extract data included in the Intent
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    Log.d("receiver", "Got message: " + message);
  }
};

@Override
protected void onPause() {
  // Unregister since the activity is not visible
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
  super.onPause();
}
```

And to Broadcast from service use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("mybroadcast");
sendBroadcast(intent)
```